# What type of coffee maker creates the most coffee scent?

Tags: chemistry, aroma

I stopped drinking coffee for a while but recently picked it back up, mainly because I enjoy the scent.  Previously I had a Keurig machine; convenient, but produces almost no smell during brewing.  Until I broke it a couple days ago, I was trying out a french press.  Again, very little of that heavenly wakeup scent.

What method of coffee making will best fill the house with coffee scent?

Comment: With the way volatile aroma compounds work, the more coffee flavor is in the air, the less flavor will be in the drink. Maybe you just need a home coffee roaster, they usually make your whole house smell like coffee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a lot of scent, you will want to make sure that nothing stops evaporation - so no lid and a large surface area are paramount.

The classic method would be hand-filtered pour-over, which system you choose is up to you, famous examples are [Melitta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melitta_Bentz), [Chemex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemex_Coffeemaker) or [Hario](https://www.hario.jp/seihin/productlist.php?bigclass=1) (which all follow the same principle). And as an additional benefit you get to enjoy the aroma right there while you are brewing the coffee.

An alternative could be Turkish [mocca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_coffee), where super-fine grounds are boiled. The boiling process will likely create more steam, on the other hand, the surface area of a [cezve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cezve) is a lot smaller than that of a filter. You will also have a quite different end product and have to decide for yourself whether that fits your expectation or not.

And in any case, I recommend grinding your beans fresh just before brewing, you’ll be surprised at how much of a difference that alone will be. And grinding also releases the coffee smell you are aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe coffee lovers consume coffee to be able to drink that smell. I just want to add to Stephie's answer where that smell comes from.

While roasting, during [Maillard reaction](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/quantifying-flavor-differences-between-varieties/2550#2550), the little pores in the coffee bean fills out with the emittted CO<sub>2</sub> together with traces of products of the Maillard reaction. These products are partially trapped within the bean together with CO<sub>2</sub>. Partially trapped means that they can still find cracks within the bean and going through the cracks they can go out of the bean~. Put this is limited*. Still, some flavor is trapped inside.

Then, when you grind the bean, you crack open all the holes and let the flavors carried together with CO<sub>2</sub>. CO<sub>2</sub> molecule has a very small molecular mass^, so it really travels fast through the air to your nose.

Based on this story we can conclude that:

- bean characteristics
- fresher roast
- finer ground

positively affect the amount of smell. Then, you can extract more flavors and evaporate them during brewing. I assume this part has already been answered.

- (~) This is what you smell from the little valve of packed coffee beans
- (*) This is what happens during [degassing](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/6/why-is-it-not-recommended-to-drink-coffee-immediately-after-its-roasted).
- (^) 44.0095 g/mol. [See Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128090/how-fast-do-molecules-move-in-objects).